# Proving $ \overset{\circ}{E} \cap \overset{\circ}{F} =\overset{\circ}{( E \cap F )}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm trying to prove $ \overset{\circ}{E} \cap \overset{\circ}{F} =\overset{\circ}{( E \cap F )}$. For clarification, I take $\overset{\circ}{E}$ to mean the interior of E. I believe I've done one direction correctly:

> Let $x \in  \overset{\circ}{E} \cap \overset{\circ}{F} $. Then $ x \in \overset{\circ}{E}$ and $x \in \overset{\circ}{F}$. Then $\exists R_1, R_2 > 0$ such that $Nr_1(X) \subset E$ and $Nr_2(x) \subset E$. If we let $R = min\{r_1, r_2\}$, then it follows that $Nr(P) \subset Nr_1 (p) \cap Nr_2 (p) \subset E \cap F$. Since r is positive, $p \in \overset{\circ}{(E \cap F)} $.

However, I'm having difficulty in proving the other direction. Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Per discussion and @G.Snapsmath's answer, are you only proving this in the context of metric spaces (or doing real-analysis with the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$), or do you want to show this for $E,F \subset X$ where $(X, \mathcal{T})$ is any topology?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $p\in \overset{\circ}{E\cap F}$ then there is some $R>0$ so that $N_R(p)\subset E\cap F$. By definition of intersection, $N_R(p)\subset E$ and $N_R(p)\subset F$. Then you can conclude.

Comment: That would depend on the specific topology, wouldn't it?

Comment: I assumed Nikitau was using the metric topology, as he/she used positive real numbers and neighborhoods.

Comment: Sorry! I am referring to the metric topology. Thank you @G.Snapsmath!

Comment: @nikitau You should probably click the "check" by the answer to accept this as the answer to your question, since it seems to have done so :)